# Classic books about various topics in mathematics (from Game theory to Optimal Transport)

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, partial-differential-equations, optimization, book-recommendation

Looking for **classical books** about the following topics of Mathematics, the **must-reads** so to speak. The books should be understandable for **graduate students**.

1. Game Theory,
2. Random Matrix Theory,
3. statistical Physics,
4. Differentialgeometry,
5. Control theory,
6. Optimal Transport (e.g. "Optimal transport, old and new" by Villani).

Any recommendation is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

For game theory, I recommend Osborne and Rubinstein, A Course in Game Theory
https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/course-game-theory. It is aimed at graduate students, and you need some mathematical maturity (willingness to sit down and puzzle things out for a while) but does not require previous knowledge of game theory.

A classic must read is Schelling`s The Strategy of Conflict which has some brilliant ideas and doesn't require much math at all. He got the Nobel prize for the ideas in this book.